# currentSrc not working inside jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-video

"currentSrc" is the only option I have to switch source src in html5 video in with multiple source (*.mp3, *.ogg etc.)

"currentSrc" throws "undefined" if I use inside Jquery.
But it works fine, if I call this in the html page.

In detail:
My Video Source:

```
<video width="630" height="354" id="video1" class="video1" poster="asserts/poster.png" controls="controls" data-name="demo video" data-uid="57fb2708">
        <source src="http://static.clipcanvas.com/sample/clipcanvas_14348_H264_320x180.mp4" data-quality="sd" />
        <source src="asserts/samllfile.mp4" data-quality="hd" />
        <source src="http://static.clipcanvas.com/elephants-dream.webm" data-quality="hd" />
        <source src="http://video.webmfiles.org/big-buck-bunny_trailer.webm" data-quality="sd"/>
        <source src="http://video.webmfiles.org/elephants-dream.webm" data-quality="hd" />
</video>
```

Get current video URL

Javascript in the html page (which works fine):

```
myVid=document.getElementById("video1");
    function getVid(){
        alert(myVid.currentSrc);
    };
```

Line inside Jquery (throws "undefined"):

```
alert($hdVideo.currentSrc);
```

Please help me out...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because a jQuery object does not have a property currentSrc so it returns undefined.

```
alert( $hdVideo.get(0).currentSrc );
alert( $hdVideo[0].currentSrc );
alert( $hdVideo.prop("currentSrc") );   //might be attr() instead of prop()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot...

alert( $hdVideo.get(0).currentSrc );
alert( $hdVideo[0].currentSrc );

Both works in Chrome, FF, Opera

a single '0" ate half a day :( 

Thanks for your immediate help...

Answer (score 3):

DOM elements and jQuery-wrapped DOM elements do not have the same properties or methods. If you want to access a property of the DOM element from a jQuery-wrapped DOM element, you need to use `get()` or an indexor to access the underlying DOM element:

```
alert($hdVideo.get(0).currentSrc);
alert($hdVideo[0].currentSrc);
```